# Importing excel having merged cell in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

My problem is while reading excel file having column cells merged/combined. For example, read below excel data to database.

Excel Input:

```
+----+-------+---------+-------+
| ID |      NAME       | DEPT  |
+----+-------+---------+-------+
|    | FNAME | LNAME   |       |
+----+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 | Akil  | Tiwari  | IT    |
|  2 | Vinod | Rathore | IT    |
|  3 | Jatin | Khanna  | HR    |
|  4 | Divya | Kherde  | AD    |
|  5 | Amey  | Gauda   | FI    |
+----+-------+---------+-------+
```

Expected Database Output:

```
+----+-------+---------+------+
| ID | FNAME |  LNAME  | DEPT |
+----+-------+---------+------+
|  1 | Akil  | Tiwari  | IT   |
|  2 | Vinod | Rathore | IT   |
|  3 | Jatin | Khanna  | HR   |
|  4 | Divya | Kherde  | AD   |
|  5 | Amey  | Gauda   | FI   |
+----+-------+---------+------+
```

Comment: You could select the table from row 2 onwards using something like  “Select * from [Monday$A2:L1000]”` (where "Monday" is the name of the worksheet and A2:l1000 is the data range). The blank columns will then be "F1" AND "F4". I can give you more info on this if you want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just connect your excel normally the Excel Connection manager will read it like the following:

```
+----+-------+---------+-------+
| ID | NAME  | F3      | DEPT  |  <-- Header
+----+-------+---------+-------+
|    | FNAME | LNAME   |       |  <--First Row
+----+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 | Akil  | Tiwari  | IT    |  <-- Second Row
|  2 | Vinod | Rathore | IT    |   .
|  3 | Jatin | Khanna  | HR    |   .
|  4 | Divya | Kherde  | AD    |   .
|  5 | Amey  | Gauda   | FI    |   .
+----+-------+---------+-------+
```

In the Excel Source Just rename columns like below"

```
NAME --> FNAME
F3   --> LNAME
```

[image]

Then Just add a Conditional Split that filter rows that have ID = NULL using the following expression

```
ISNULL([ID]) == false
```

[image]

Then the First row will be ignored